# atlimage Draw function assert failed for hBitmap == m_hBitmap

Tags: winapi, gdi+

after i see the codes in the atlimage.h  i found that the `GetDC` function(shows below)return null.
I can't find any problems in my code. please help my. :(

these is the `GetDC` functions defines and in the call of selectobject return null.
I had no idea about what happened.

```
inline HDC CImage::GetDC() const throw()
{
    ATLASSUME( m_hBitmap != NULL );

    m_nDCRefCount++;
    if( m_hDC == NULL )
    {
        m_hDC = GetCDCCacheInstance()->GetDC();
        m_hOldBitmap = HBITMAP( ::SelectObject( m_hDC, m_hBitmap ) );
    }

    return( m_hDC );
}
```

Comment: Oh this is no  the GetDC function return null but is the m_hOldBitamp=null.

Comment: See the section on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"I can't find any problems in my code. please help"* - The bug is in your code, but we cannot see it, so we cannot help. Besides, your question title doesn't match the code you posted (and the code you posted is merely the messenger, that delivered the bad news, that your code is using the `CImage` class in a way it isn't meant to be used).